# GestureRecognizer is not working inside the ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing the Windows 8.1 application in the XAML/C#. In my application I suppose to interact the UIElement with respect to the user interactions like Zoom, Horizontal scroll.

When I surfed over the net, I found the following sample link.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-Windows-8-gestures-e0bb367d

It helped me a lot to resolve all my requirements using GestureRecognizer. However when we use GestureRecognizer inside the ScrollViewer it fails to achieve. Could you please anyone help me on this ?

Comment: I don't know wpf, nor win8. But I can assume this is something to do with disabling user interaction from being processed by `ScrollViewer`, so that `GestureRecognizer` can catch them.

Comment: I tried to set some of events that e.Handled =true in ScrollViewer but it did not work.

Comment: Potentially Helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ea597254-8d13-445c-abe5-614140ec79f0/implementing-gesturerecognition-in-a-scrollviewer

Comment: Finally It resolved my problem with the help of Chris. W. Thanks for your support.